# very interesting use of return keyword in php

Tags: php

as we know, **return** keyword will RETURN some value and exit current function. Mean, that this one used only inside some functions.

**BUT,** I saw some php-dev's use return keyword outside functions, even in index.php file (in root of web server). What is that mean???? By the way, maybe it's logical to require some file inside function, but this style isnt mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much more to say than what the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) do.

About the common usage of `return`:

> If called from within a function, the `return` statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call. return will also end the execution of
>   an `eval()` statement or script file.

About the less common usage:

> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script
>   file is ended. If the current script file was `include`d or `require`d,
>   then control is passed back to the calling file. Furthermore, if the
>   current script file was included, then the value given to return will
>   be returned as the value of the include call. If return is called from
>   within the main script file, then script execution ends. If the
>   current script file was named by the auto_prepend_file or
>   auto_append_file configuration options in php.ini, then that script
>   file's execution is ended.

Answer (score 2):

Its documented somewhere within the manual

```
// myFile.php
return array( 'foo' => 'bar');

// somewhere else
$config = include 'myFile.php';
echo $config['foo'];
```

If you use `return` in the main scope php will leave the file inclusion and use the value as "return value" of the inclusion (`include[_once]()`, `require[_once]()`).

Answer (score 1):

> BUT, I saw some php-dev's use return keyword outside functions, even
>   in index.php file (in root of web server). What is that mean???

You know the common purpose. But what you are asking is used to prevent code injection in php *include* files. Take a look at this post which explains it:

[**Prevent Code Injection in PHP include files**](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/prevent-code-injection-in-php-include-files/)

> While discussing Coding Standards it was not long ago I argued against
>   adding ?> at the end of php files. But miqrogroove pointed to me an
>   interesting aspect why it actually can make sense to have it and an
>   additional return statement at the end of each file: **That one (merely
>   the return statement) can prevent an attacker to append payload code
>   to existing PHP files, for example known include files.** The
>   countermeasurement is pretty easy, just add a return statement at the
>   end of the file. It will end the include “subroutine”:

**Example:**

```
  /* all the include file's php code */
  return;
?>
```

Comment: @whocares: Works for me: http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/prevent-code-injection-in-php-include-files/